# How can I make two or three columns list using php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

HTML

```
<ul><h2>More useful stuff...</h2>
<li><a href="#">category 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 8</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 9</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 10</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 11</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 12</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 13</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 14</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 15</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 16</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 17</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 18</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 19</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 20</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 21</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 22</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 23</a></li>
<li><a href="#">category 24</a></li>        
</ul>
```

I got a list here, My question is how could I automatically divide that list into 2 or 3 columns either using php or jquery

I dont know how to use the for loop in php

Comment: use css. This is what it's designed for.

Comment: Dont use what you don't understand is a key rule in the programming world.

Comment: PHP for loop docs http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this jQuery plugin called [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

Just put all of that code in to a block like a `<div id="list">` and use this function to columnize all the content

```
$('#list').columnize({ columns: 3 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul><h2>More useful stuff...</h2>       
    <?php
        for($i = 0; $i < 21;$i++)
        {
            if($i % 7 == 0)
            {
                echo "</ul>";
                echo "<ul style='float:left;'>";
            }
            echo "<li><a href='#'>category " . $i . "</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

There you go buddy. Like relentless mentioned, the best way is CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the help....that works ok

well, I just used that columnizer plugin, pretty easy to use

Comment: jquery ftw =) I still think CSS is the way to go, though. Javascript/JQuery is used to optimalize your website, not to be dependent on them.